# Django filter feature with ajax not working

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a table for tracking job applications and im trying to implement a filter feature. I want to display the results with pagination. However, I am getting errors when trying to do so and can't seem to find my way out of it. I want the results to be displayed without the page being refreshed. I think the issue is with the queries.

Please help.... :(((

Here is my code:

template file

```
 <ul id="filter_list" class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#">Alphabetical Order (A-Z)</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Application Date (Ascending)</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Application Date (Descending)</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Closing Date</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div id="table_results">

 <div>

 <script>

    $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
    var selected_filter = $(this).text();


    $.ajax({
        url:'{% url "stu_filter_applications" %}',
        data:{
            "filter_category": selected_filter,
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (response) {
            //I want the page to not refresh here                  
            },
          error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.errors);
          },
        });

    });
</script>
```

views.py:

```
def stu_filter_applications(request):
    filter_cat = request.GET.get("filter_category", None)
    student = StudentUser.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if filter_cat == "Alphabetical Order (A-Z)":       
        int_applications = 
        InternshipApplication.objects.filter(student=student).
        order_by('internship__internship_title')

    if filter_cat == "Application Date (Ascending)":
        int_applications = 
        InternshipApplication.objects.filter(student=student).
        order_by('application_date')

    if filter_cat == "Application Date (Descending)":
        int_applications = 
        InternshipApplication.objects.filter(student=student).
        order_by('-application_date')

    if filter_cat == "Closing Date":
         int_applications = 
         InternshipApplication.objects.filter(student=student).
         order_by('-internship__internship_deadline')

     applications = []

    for app in int_applications:
        internship = Internship.objects.get(id=app.internship.id)
        recruiter = Recruiter.objects.get(id=internship.recruiter.id)
        applications.append((internship,recruiter,app))


    for internship, recruiter, app in applications:
        print(internship)
        print(recruiter)
        print(app)

    paginator = Paginator(applications, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

        try:
            applications = paginator.page(page)

        except PageNotAnInteger:
            applications = paginator.page(1)

        except EmptyPage:
            applications = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context = {    
              'applications': applications,
              'filter_by': filter_cat,
         }
            return render(request,'track_internship.html', context)
```

track_internship.html

```
<ul id="filter_list" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Alphabetical Order (A-Z)</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Application Date (Ascending)</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Application Date (Descending)</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Closing Date</a></li>
</ul>
     

        
  <table style="width:100%; margin-top: 20px;"  id="app_table" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="background-color:#012D6C; color:white;" 
            class="table_row">
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Link to advert</th>
                        <th>Posted Date</th>
                        <th>Closing Date</th>
                        <th>Application Date</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

        <div id="table_results">
                <tbody>
                    {% for internship, recruiter, app in applications %}
                    <tr style="background-color: #E9F4FF" class="table_row">
                        <td>{{ recruiter.company_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ internship.internship_title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ internship.internship_mode}}</td>
                        <td><a style="color:blue; text-decoration: 
                underline;" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_details/{{ 
                internship.id }}">Click here</a></td>
                        <td>{{ internship.posted_date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ internship.internship_deadline }}</td>
                        <td>{{ app.application_date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ app.status }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor%}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        

        {% if applications.has_other_pages %}
        
        <div class="pagination">
            {% if applications.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ applications.previous_page_number }}"><i 
            class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            {% else %}
                <a class="disabled"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria- 
             hidden="true"></i></span></a>
            {% endif %}
            
            {% if applications.number|add:'-2' > 1 %}
                <a href="?page={{ applications.number|add:'-3' }}">&hellip; 
            </a>
            {% endif %}
            
            {% for i in applications.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if applications.number == i %}
                    <a class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only"> 
                (current)</span></span></a>
                {% elif i > applications.number|add:'-3' and i < 
            applications.number|add:'3' %}
                    <a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            
            {% if applications.paginator.num_pages > 
             applications.number|add:'4' %}
                <a href="?page={{ applications.number|add:'3' }}">&hellip; 
            </a>
            {% endif %}
            
            {% if applications.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ applications.next_page_number }}"><i 
            class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            {% else %}
                <a class="disabled"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" 
            aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
            {% endif %}
```

models.py

```
class StudentUser(models.Model):

   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, 
   null=True, blank=True)

 class Internship(models.Model):

     recruiter = models.ForeignKey(Recruiter, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
     internship_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     internship_deadline = models.DateField()
 

 class InternshipApplication(models.Model):
     internship = models.ForeignKey(Internship, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     student = models.ForeignKey(StudentUser,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
     application_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are facing? It's not clear what you want to do, so if you filter results you want the ajax call to populate new data and then move between pages for the filtered result please make it more clear.

Comment: @AAB, I have a table which displays the results in a paginated form. Upon clicking on a filter, for instance to sort by closing date, I want the page to update but this time with the jobs being sorted by the closing date. I hope I was clear.

Comment: can you post the error it will easier to debug

Comment: @AAB, Im nt getting errors but it's not working. Previously, it was telling me that the attribute internship.internship_title does not exist for that object. same for closing_date. But now, it isnt saying that ://

Comment: if you remove request.is_ajax(), and open the url with parameters for page and filter it prints nothing? you are returning html so somethng should be printed cant be blank can you post the html that you are rendering?

Comment: @AAB, yeah i mean it prints the normal page without the filtered results. I updated the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232994/discussion-between-alpha-and-aab).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your model, template,view you need to change the following things:

1. change internship.internship_deadline to internship__internship_deadline and internship.internship_title to internship__internship_title.
2. You can pass internship, recruiter, int_applications as separate objects. int_applications should return multiple objects unlike recruiter and internship where you have used .get()
3. In the templates for pagination to work with orderby the url must be as follows:

   ?page=value&filter_category=value
4. In your views.py it seems you are just ordering values based on user input so I would recommend changing it to order_by as you are not filtering anything but ordering.

Comment: I updated the code for views.py. Can you help further please?

Comment: for part 3 and 4